# find Cliques in a graph using golang

Tags: algorithm, graph, go

I am trying to write an algorithm which will find all [Cliques (complete subgraphs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_(graph_theory)) in a graph. Each input vertex must be only in one resulting Clique. The algorithm must have `O(N^2)` time complexity. Each clique in the result must be as big as possible.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Vertex struct {
    Value int
}

type CompleteSubGraph struct {
    vertecies []Vertex
}

func areConnected(vertex1, vertex2 Vertex) bool {
    // 2 verteces are connected if their value sum is even
    return (vertex1.Value+vertex2.Value)%2 == 0
}

func (vertex1 Vertex) getConnectedVertices(vertices []Vertex, maxVertices int) (verticesConnectedWithVertex1 []Vertex) {
    for _, vertex2 := range vertices {
        if areConnected(vertex1, vertex2) {
            verticesConnectedWithVertex1 = append(verticesConnectedWithVertex1, vertex2)
        }
        if len(verticesConnectedWithVertex1) >= maxVertices {
            break
        }
    }
    return
}

func findAllCompleteSubGraphs(
    vertices []Vertex,
    maximumNumberOfVerticesForSubGraph int,
) (allCompleteSubgraphs []*CompleteSubGraph) {
    /*
       every vertex from input vertices
       must be only in one CompleteSubGraph

       the Algorithm must work not slower than O(N^2)
       where N is len(vertices)

       each vertex from input vertices must be only in one
       resulting CompleteSubGraph

       each CompleteSubGraph must be as big as possible
    */
    for _, vertex1 := range vertices {
        connectedToVertex1 := vertex1.getConnectedVertices(vertices,
            maximumNumberOfVerticesForSubGraph)
        fmt.Println("vertex", vertex1)
        fmt.Println("is connected to", connectedToVertex1)
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    vertices := []Vertex{
        Vertex{Value: 1}, Vertex{Value: 2}, Vertex{Value: 3},
        Vertex{Value: 4}, Vertex{Value: 5}, Vertex{Value: 6},
        Vertex{Value: 7}, Vertex{Value: 8}, Vertex{Value: 9},
        Vertex{Value: 10}, Vertex{Value: 11}, Vertex{Value: 12},
    }
    fmt.Println("result", findAllCompleteSubGraphs(vertices, 3))
}
```

I am checking if 2 vertecies are connected by an edge using `areConnected` function. It's simple just for example but will be more complicated in real life.

I have to use `func (vertex1 Vertex) getConnectedVertices` as it is defined now.
I stuck on the cycle

```
        for _, vertex1 := range vertices {
            connectedToVertex1 := vertex1.getConnectedVertices(vertices,
                maximumNumberOfVerticesForSubGraph)
            fmt.Println("vertex", vertex1)
            fmt.Println("is connected to", connectedToVertex1)
        }
```

Can hardly imagine how to finish the algorithm. Will appriciate any advise.

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/oDLQAxQFbI)

## Update

The original problem which I am trying to solve:
Find groups of people who fit each other by some characteristics. `AreConnected` is true when `person1` likes `person2` and `person2` likes `person1`. The task is to create groups of people with maximum size by a list of people. It is believed that big groups are better than small groups.

Comment: Your definition for `areConnected` will possibly change every time you call it.  How can you determine the cliques of a graph if the edges of your graph randomly appear and disappear every time you try to check if an edge exists?  You should use randomness to generate a graph up front for your test case, but then your algorithm, and determining whether two vertices are connected, should be deterministic.

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta I fixed `areConnected` function above, thank you

Comment: What is the point of the `maximumNumberOfVerticesForSubGraph` argument?  In your problem description, you don't say anything about this, you simply say "each clique in the result must be as large as possible".

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta resulting cliques must be not bigger than `maximumNumberOfVerticesForSubGraph int` value

Comment: Actually, what does it mean when you say "each clique in the result must be as large as possible" but also "each input vertex must be only in one resulting Clique."  Suppose you have a graph that's a chain of three vertices: ` X----X----X`.  There are two maximal cliques, but they are overlapping (both share the middle vertex).

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta in this case the algorithm must return 2 cliques: X----X, X. The first has 2 vertecies. The second is only one vertex. Each clique in the result must be as large as possible as long as each input vertex is only in one resulting Clique.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91455/discussion-between-amit-kumar-gupta-and-maxim-yefremov).

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta It's most likely a homework assignment. `O(n^2)` isn't really enough time to do anything but greedily grab a maximal clique and repeat.

Answer (score 1):

O(n^2) isn't enough time to enumerate all possible cliques in a graph, even if we (incredibly optimistically) assume O(1) processing time per clique.  Consider an n-vertex graph consisting of n/3 disjoint triangles -- that is, n/3 sets of 3 vertices, with each vertex having edges to the other 2 vertices in its group and to no other vertices.  Notice that you can independently choose a single vertex from each of the n/3 triangles to get an independent set (a set of n/3 vertices, no two of which are connected by an edge).  Now invert all edges in this graph: this gives a graph in which the same choice of vertices now gives a clique of size n/3.  There are 3^(n/3) cliques of this size, all of which are maximal (cannot have any vertices added to them and remain cliques).  3^(n/3) is *much* larger than n^2, so you cannot hope to even list all these cliques in O(n^2) time.